# How to implement skype-like action bar design in android(custom action bar)

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am an intermediate android developer and i have an app that should have a custom designed action bar.I have researched and noticed that skype uses a customised action bar at the top.How did they implement that?I only need pointing to the right direction and the rest i can do myself.
Below is a screenshot of  the skype design am talking about.

[image]

Comment: i think you can add custom layout to the action bar.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this for anyone who might find it helpful.The action bar in android is a bit rigid and doesn't offer a developer much freedom for styling it.Instead style the window title bar to suit your design taste. That's how i achieved my design.
Tutorials on how to do that are all over the internet,and the best thing about it is its really simple.